# Change the value of a textbox in a template field from event outside of GridView

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I need to be able to change the value of a TextBox(s) in a GridView template field from a TextChanged event. So the user can enter some text in a TextBox outside of the Gridview and then the TextBox(s) in the GridView gets updated to what the user entered.

This is what I need to do:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    template_text_box1.Text( in template field ) = TextBox1.Text << (TextBox1)( outside of gridview )
}
```

I have tried `FindControl`. This needs to happen without using any of the GridView events. I am just stumped. Could someone point me in the right direction? Maybe some JavaScript?

Comment: in which row you want add value.i mean how you decide in which row of grid view it goes...

Comment: If you want all rows, you will need to loop through the rows and reference the column that the TextBox is defined to set the text.

Comment: Every row in the gridview. How do you reference the column and then the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you would want to define a separate TextBox for the display and do something like the following:

```
double value1;

private void template textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if textBox1.Text (Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value1))
    {
        textBox15 = value1.ToString();
    }
}
```

This way you can make your other TextBox outside the grid and be able to call it and set to the value that is inputted.

Answer (score 0):

On the .Aspx page, in the GridView column template TextBox add a CSS class.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="box-to-change" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

Also on the .Aspx page add a JavaScript function that uses jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateAllTextboxes(value)
{
    $('input.box-to-change').val(value);
}
</script>
```

In the code-behind add the JavaScript function as a client `OnChange` event (will not require PostBack).

```
otherTextBox.Attributes["onchange"] = "updateAllTextboxes(this.value)";
```

Comment: I know this part. I need to figure out how to change the textbox text in the gridview.